# Hash table and Hash map in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, hash, hashmap, hashtable

Internal representation of a hashtable && hashmap is,

### [image]

In Java, *hashtable* and *hashmap* is differentiated in terms of synchronous/asynchronous operation, otherwise internal representation is same.

Javascript object literal notation,

```
var obj = {
           e1: 1,
           e2: 2,
           e3: 3  
         };
```

can be directly used as hashtable and hashmap with its internal hashing function. Object literal has string or Symbols as keys.

ES6 has also introduced `window.Map` with any value as keys.

1) Does the above internal representation for hashtable and hashmap, looks correct? (or) Is there a difference in internal represenation of hashtable and hashmap?

2) Does Javascript object literal provide O(1) computation for hashtable/hashmap without any collision?

Comment: see this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241676/javascript-objects-as-hashes-is-the-complexity-greater-than-o1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your picture is *one* way to implement a [hash table data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) - there are others. Your image is an example of "separate chaining", "open addressing" is another common strategy. As of Java 7 both [`Hashtable`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Hashtable.java) and [`HashMap`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) used a form of chaining (look at their `Entry` classes), however Java 8 introduced a massive rewrite of [`HashMap`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) (but not [`Hashtable`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Hashtable.java), as it's a legacy class) to use a tree structure rather than a linked list for its chains. The point being the exact algorithm used by both classes is an implementation detail and is subject to change between releases.

"HashMap" and "Hashtable" are just class names defined by the JDK, they do not necessarily correspond to particular hashing algorithms. JavaScript does not have separate "HashMap" and "Hashtable" concepts, because they don't need them. Java needed to create a separate `HashMap` class because the `Hashtable` contract was problematic and couldn't be safely corrected.

So, to answer your questions:

1) Sort-of; it does not properly represent Java 8's `HashMap`, but it's conceptually not far off. `Hashtable` does still use this algorithm, but you should almost never use `Hashtable`.

2) Like you say, JavaScript objects use a hash table data structure under the covers. This does (generally) provide O(1) field access, but like any hash table implementation it must deal with the possibility of conflicts. As discussed in the question @overexchange linked to the [exact implementation is browser-dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36598093/113632).